# How to parse PokeAPI's [Obect] and [Array] in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, discord.js

this is my first post on stackoverflow.
I am currently working on a [discord bot.](https://github.com/mystzd/mystbot) I am attempting right now to add in commands to view pokemon stats.

So far I have been able to get the name, ID, and weight of the pokemon. That is fine, but I feel there can be more data that can be gleamed from the API.

Here is my current code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Command = require('../../../base/Command.js');

class pokemonLookup extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
        name: 'pokesearch',
        description: 'Look up a pokemon!',
        aliases: ['ps'],
        guildOnly: false,
        ownerOnly: false,
        category: 'Pokemon',
        extended: 'Search some information about any pokemon. (Correct spelling is required.'
    })
    }

    async run(message, args) {

    let pokemon = args[0];

    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
        const name = data.species.name;
        const url = data.species.url;
        const weight = data.weight / 10;
        const em = new RichEmbed();
        em.setTitle('Pokemon Stats');
        em.setDescription(`Name: [${name.toUpperCase()}](${url})`);
        em.addField('Pokedox Number', data.id);
        em.addField('Weight (kg)', weight);
        em.setThumbnail(data.sprites.front_default);

        message.channel.send(em)
        })
    }
}
module.exports = pokemonLookup
```

If I print `(data)` to the console, I get this:

```
moves: 
   [ { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] },
     { move: [Object], version_group_details: [Array] }
]
```

And since on their [website](https://pokeapi.co), they have the `move` and `version_group_details` clearly listed, I was wondering how to go about retrieving that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily log this information by doing:

```js
console.log(data.moves[0].move)
console.log(data.moves[0].version_group_details)
```

it will return something along the lines of this:

```js
>> {......} // move
>> [......] // version_group_details
```